# My h4 tag is being cut off

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website using Bootstrap 3 and when I add an h4 tag it gets cut off at the edge of the page.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jordanbaron123/pen/dXjJXp)

I am using the latest version of Bootstrap 3

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Remove the comma `,` from this elements class `<div class="container, row">`

Comment: delete , between row and container

Comment: As this being a typo, I suggest you close it as such, or delete it all together

Answer (score -1):

Remove the row class from the `<div class="container, row">`,it add the more -15px margin both right and left to make sure the row is centered.Or you can remove the comma in case you need the `row` class

Answer (score -2):

There are some mistakes in HTML.

```
<div class="container row"> Remove row class and at the top of HTML remove container class as it is not required.
https://codepen.io/shahi_rupali/pen/qNypXN
```